# extending a namespace in prototypejs

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, javascript-framework

To extend a class, e.g. Element, in Prototype.js, I do it like this (update me if this changed)

```
var myFunctions = {

    custom: function(element)   
    {
        # yadda yadda

        return element;
    }

};


Element.addMethods(myFunctions);
```

Now prototype has some namespaces, like Form. I want to extend Form.Element because I need some custom functions to work on my form inputs.

Trying

```
Form.Element.addMethods(myFunctions);
```

throws

```
Error: Form.Element.addMethods is not a function
```

How can i do this properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`addMethods()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Class/prototype/addMethods/) is a method of [`Class`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Class/). [`Element`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/) is a class. [`Form`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/) and [`Form.Element`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/Element/) are objects. Try using [`Object.extend()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Object/extend/):

```
 Object.extend(Form.Element, myFunctions);
```

Or more simply since each object is a unique instance you can work on it directly. Although `Object.extend` looks neater when adding several functions.

```
Form.Element.custom = function(element)   
{
    # yadda yadda

    return element;
}
```